# fitch style proof problem regarding rule of inferences

Tags: logic

[image]

Okay I have the following fitch proof almost figured out, from here I know I have to move forth in conlcuding but I don't know what I am missing

(2 premises)

S → (R ∨ P)

P → (¬R → Q)

### my work below

new scope assume S   Rule: > elim

R ∨ P

New scope assume R

Q∨R     Rule: V intro

End scope – (new scope assume P)

¬R → Q         Rule: > Elim

*my confusion comes where I go from here*

Q∨R            rule Taut Con ??

Goal:├ S → (Q ∨ R)

Comment: Try typing it again inside

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [formal-logic-fitch-exercise](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/47773/formal-logic-fitch-exercise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not assume $p$, rather assume $\neg r$ and use the Law of Excluded Middle.

$\begin{array}{r|l:l} 1& s \to r\vee p \\[-1ex]
2 & p\to(\neg r\to q)\\[-1ex]
3 & \underline{\vert\quad s\qquad} \\[-1ex]
4 & \vert\quad r\vee p\\[-1ex]
5 & \vert\quad\underline{\vert\quad r\qquad}\\[-1ex]
6 & \vert\quad\vert\quad q\vee r \\[-1ex]
7 & \vert\quad r\to q\vee r\\[-1ex]
8 & \vert\quad\underline{\vert\quad \neg r\qquad}\\[-1ex]
9 & \vert\quad\vert\quad p\\[-1ex]
10 & \vert\quad\vert\quad \neg r\to q\\[-1ex]
11 & \vert\quad\vert\quad q\\[-1ex]
12 & \vert\quad\vert\quad q\vee r\\[-1ex]
13 & \vert\quad \neg r\to q\vee r\\[-1ex]
14 & \vert\quad r\vee\neg r & \star\\[-1ex]
15 & \vert\quad q\vee r\\[-1ex]
16 & s\to q\vee r
\end{array}$

---

Revision: No, of course you *may* assume $p$ and move the LEM into the subproof.   It makes the proof a little longer, but Disjunctive Syllogism may not be available as a basic rule for inference.

$\begin{array}{r|l:l} 1& s \to r\vee p \\[-1ex]
2 & p\to(\neg r\to q)\\[-1ex]
3 & \underline{\vert\quad s \qquad}\\[-1ex]
4 & \vert\quad r\vee p\\[-1ex]
5 & \vert\quad\underline{\vert\quad r\qquad}\\[-1ex]
6 & \vert\quad\vert\quad q\vee r \\[-1ex]
7 & \vert\quad r\to q\vee r\\[-1ex]
8 & \vert\quad\underline{\vert\quad p\qquad}\\[-1ex]
9 & \vert\quad\vert\quad \neg r\to q\\[-1ex]
11 & \vert\quad\vert\quad\underline{\vert\quad \neg r\qquad}\\[-1ex]
12 & \vert\quad\vert\quad\vert\quad q\\[-1ex]
13 & \vert\quad\vert\quad\vert\quad q\vee r\\[-1ex]
14 & \vert\quad\vert\quad \neg r\to q\vee r\\[-1ex]
15 & \vert\quad\vert\quad r\vee\neg r & \star\\[-1ex]
16 & \vert\quad\vert\quad q\vee r\\[-1ex]
17 & \vert\quad p\to q\vee r\\[-1ex]
18 & \vert\quad  q\vee r\\[-1ex]
19 & s\to q\vee r
\end{array}$

Comment: wow I totally see how my approach was incorrect but this clarifies a lot, thankyou!!